# Any way to see "Optional add-ons' list of a software in new Ubuntu Software center in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: software-center, 16.04, plugins

In older version of Ubuntu software center I can see the `Optional add-ons` list below of software description. Like the picture (indicated by circle)..

[image]

But in new version of Ubuntu Software center there is no list. Like the picture..

[image]

Is ther any way to see the list (like first picture) in new version of Ubuntu Software center in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu software center in 14.04 does not same with 16.04.
Package name in 14.04 is `software-center`, in 16.04 `ubuntu-software`.

In my case, I just install the old ones.
`sudo apt-get install software-center`